# Where a vector would intersect the screen if extended towards it's direction (swift)

Tags: swift, geometry

I'm trying to write a function in swift, which returns a CGPoint where the extension of a vector (which is within a screen) will intersect the screen. Let's assume that the screen is 800 x 600. It's like the scheme:

[image: the screen scheme]

The function should have the following parameters:

```
func calcPoint(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
```

- start: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1) - this is the beginning of the vector.
- end: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1) - this is the end point of the vector.
- the return point is the one at which the vector intersects the screen (CGPoint(x: x3, y: y3) as shown at the scheme).

The values for the vector start and end are aways points within the screen (the rectangle 0, 0, 800, 600).

**EDIT** (for Alexander):
Is there a formula, which in the given situation will make it easy to write the function, in not the obvious way using if ... else ... and triangle vertices ratio?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Now you have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute point E you can look at the triangles given by your setting. You have the Triangle ABC and DBE. Note that they are similar, such that we can set up following relation AB : AC = DB : DE using the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) (AB etc. stands for the line segment between A and B). In the given setting you know all points but E.

[image]

Using start and end Points from given setting:

[image]

In case start and end have the same x or y-coordinate it is only the top bottom or left right border with the same coordinate.

Using the absolute values it should work for all four corners of your rectangle. Then of course you have to consider E being out of your rectangle, again the same relation can be used AB : AC = D'B : D'E'

[image]

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately going this direction will require to test for 8 cases: when the vector is parallel to x or y based on the direction you have 4 cases and when the direction of the vector is one of the 4 possible - there are the other 4 cases.

Comment: Yes I know I would assume that using the absolute values will reduce the cases though. In theory most problems have nice solutions, implementation is always a different story.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. I will accept it if there is no other within 1-2 days. I'm trying to make a nicer solution. For example if we take the starting point of the vector as point 0,0 of a coordinate system, then we would be dealing only with angle (0 - 360 degrees) and coordinate system translation.

Answer (score 1):

A pure swift solution for everyone interested in such (thanks to Ivo Ivanoff):

```
// Example for iOS
/// The height of the screen
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
/// The width of the screen 
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

func calculateExitPoint(from anchor : CGPoint, to point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    var exitPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint()
    let directionV: CGFloat = anchor.y < point.y ? 1 : -1
    let directionH: CGFloat = anchor.x < point.x ? 1 : -1
    let a   = directionV > 0 ? screenHeight - anchor.y : anchor.y
    let a1  = directionV > 0 ? point.y - anchor.y : anchor.y - point.y
    let b1  = directionH > 0 ? point.x - anchor.x : anchor.x - point.x
    let b   = a / (a1 / b1)
    let tgAlpha = b / a
    let b2 = directionH > 0 ? screenWidth - point.x : point.x
    let a2 = b2 / tgAlpha
    exitPoint.x = anchor.x + b * directionH
    exitPoint.y = point.y + a2 * directionV
    if (exitPoint.x > screenWidth) {
        exitPoint.x = screenWidth
    } else if (exitPoint.x < 0) {
        exitPoint.x = 0;
    } else {
        exitPoint.y = directionV > 0 ? screenHeight : 0
    }
    return exitPoint
}
```

Any kind of optimizations are welcomed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no single formula, because intersection depends on starting point position, line slope and rectangle size, and it may occur at any rectangle edge.

Here is approach based on parametric representation of line. Works for any slope (including horizontal and vertical). Finds what border is intersected first, calculates intersection point.

```
dx = end.x - start.x
dy = end.y - start.y

//parametric equations for reference:
//x = start.x + dx * t
//y = start.y + dy * t

//prerequisites: potential border positions
if dx > 0 then
   bx = width
else
   bx = 0

if dy > 0 then
   by = height
else
   by = 0

//first check for horizontal/vertical lines 
if dx = 0 then
    return ix = start.x,  iy = by

if dy = 0 then
    return iy = start.y,  ix = bx


//in general case find parameters of intersection with horizontal and vertical edge
tx = (bx - start.x) / dx
ty = (by - start.y) / dy

//and get intersection for smaller parameter value
if tx <= ty then
   ix = bx
   iy = start.y + tx * dy
else
   iy = by
   ix = start.x + ty * dx

return ix, iy
```