# How can I detect what side the ray has hit a wall in a raycaster game engine?

Tags: c, math, raycasting

I've been writing a raycaster since 2 days ago. I am using a simple and fast algorithm for detecting walls using rays. It's C btw. My question is: what check should I use to detect what face of the wall did the ray hit? I've been thinking about checking if the ray Y component is larger than the ray X component, and that would mean that I've hit the left and right faces. Right? I'm not really sure.
Full code here:

```c
    double rayAngle, wallX, wallY, rayX, rayY, h, distance, lineHeight, lineOffset, cameraAngle, shadeDistance;
    for (double ray = 0; ray < FOV * RAY_PER_DEG; ray++) // we want to raycast FOV * RAYS_PER_DEG rays
    {
        rayAngle = playerAngle + TO_RADIANS(ray / RAY_PER_DEG - FOV / 2); // set the ray angle derived from the ray index
        wallX = playerX; // set current wall coordinates to player's
        wallY = playerY; //
        rayY = sin(rayAngle) * DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT; // use vector decomposition to determine X and Y components of the ray
        rayX = cos(rayAngle) * DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT; // 
 
        for(distance = 0; distance < MAX_DISTANCE; distance++) // check for ray collision
        {
            wallX = wallX + rayX; // increase wall coordinates
            wallY = wallY + rayY;
 
            if (wallX < mapWidth && wallY < mapHeight &&       // check for wall boundaries
                wallX >= 0 && wallY >= 0 &&
                mapWalls[(int)wallY * mapHeight + (int)wallX]) // check for wall to be present
            {
                break;
            }
        }
 
        // fisheye compensation
        cameraAngle = playerAngle - rayAngle; // determine the camera angle
        WRAP_AROUND_RADIANS(cameraAngle);
        distance = distance * cos(cameraAngle); // adjust distance by x component of camera angle
 
        lineHeight = WALL_HEIGHT * MAX_WALL_HEIGHT / distance;
        lineOffset = WALL_HEIGHT - lineHeight/2; // move the line at middle
 
        // draw the ray on the map
        shadeDistance = 1 / distance;
 
        glLineWidth(1 / RESOLUTION);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(shadeDistance * SHADE_COEFFICIENT, 0, 0); // wall
        glVertex2f(ray / RESOLUTION, lineHeight + lineOffset);
        glVertex2f(ray / RESOLUTION, lineOffset);
 
        glColor3f(0, shadeDistance * SHADE_COEFFICIENT, 0); // floor
        glVertex2f(ray / RESOLUTION, lineOffset);
        glVertex2f(ray / RESOLUTION, 0);
        glEnd();
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/BsNYvXPf
Feel free to tell me anything about the code.
Edit: I have to know this to implement texture mapping.

Comment: see [Ray Casting with different height size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) for some inspiration and cross check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent ray in parametric coordinates

```
x = x0 + dx * t
y = y0 + dy * t
```

In your case `dx=cos(rayAngle), dy=sin(rayAngle)`, and `(dx,dy)` is unit direction vector.

Check intersections with vertical and horizontal line

```
 x0 + dx * t1 = wallX
 y0 + dy * t2 = wallY
```

get t1, t2

```
t1 = (wallX - x0) / dx
t2 = (wallY - y0) / dy
```

and smaller value from `t1,t2` tells us what wall will be met first.

`increase wall coordinates`  - do walls move?

Comment: regarding first 2 equations, what I should really use for t?

Comment: It is just parameter. It is 0 in the beginning of a ray and increases along the ray. Parameter t=1 corresponds to the point at distance 1 from the beginning and so on.

Comment: so x and y will be the final ray coordinates and x0 and y0 will be the initial (the player's in my case) right?

Comment: x and y are current coordinates for every parameter (like functions `x(t),y(t)`).  `x0, y0` - yes, player coordinates

Comment: I updated the code, it works to some extent (it's very bendy and has weird artifacting when next to the walls, also the walls on the back side of the player don't even render) https://pastebin.com/XFyn0r0x https://imgur.com/a/q6CidC5 (why does imgur think my screenshot is spicy?)

Comment: No, you don't implement this approach properly. You have to find parameters (distance) for possible intersections. Answer edited. And I assume standing walls. Look at description for intersection of ray with box walls (screen): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45371894/844416

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255741/discussion-between-moldytzu-and-mbo).